# Magento - Marking CMS Pages As “Active” In Navigation

Tags: javascript, php, xml, magento

Very simple one I guess, but there doesn’t seem to be an obvious write up about this. Adding the CMS pages to the nav menu is quirky for sure, but how do you mark them as active after using the URL Redirection method?

If someone could share the instructions for myself and the good of the community, that would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento 1.7 or higher, [here is a nice way to add anything in the main menu](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/7329/146).

The idea is to use the event `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before` to add nodes to the main tree.
When adding a node (menu item) you can specify a condition for it to be selected in the array item `is_active`.